# Will installing thousands of fonts slow down my pc?

Tags: windows, performance, fonts

Will installing one thousand fonts slow down my pc? I guess it would cause the editing apps to list fonts slower than before but maybe windows needs time to look for the default fonts among all. I have many fonts but I avoid installing them. Should I avoid installing a thousand fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will slow-down your graphic applications which uses fonts a lot, other-wise your pc will not go slow